# Merge 2 Json php url file into 1 php url

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, merge

I have 2 Json PHP URL and need to merge into 1.

**1st Json PHP URL - completehouse.php**

```
    [
{
          "G": "7TH DIVISION",
          "G1": "2031892",
          "DOOR": "8907",
          "AA": "81",
          "AI": "8745524"
        },
{
          "G": "8TH DIVISION",
          "G1": "4526892",
          "DOOR": "8877",
          "AA": "85",
          "AI": "8759544"
        }
      ]
```

**2nd Json PHP URL - completeflat.php**

```
{
  "Error": "",
  "ErrorCode": 0,
  "Guid": "",
  "Id": 0,
  "Success": true,
  "Value": [
    {
              "G": "6TH DIVISION",
              "G1": "6058974",
              "DOOR": "1245",
              "AA": "67",
              "AI": "6872145"
            },
    {
              "G": "5TH DIVISION",
              "G1": "5891211",
              "DOOR": "1246",
              "AA": "68",
              "AI": "5100214"
            }
          ]

}
```

What I need is to merge these 2 file and get in completebuilding.php

**Desired Output**

```
    {
  "Error": "",
  "ErrorCode": 0,
  "Guid": "",
  "Id": 0,
  "Success": true,
  "Value": [
    {
      "G": "6TH DIVISION",
      "G1": "6058974",
      "DOOR": "1245",
      "AA": "67",
      "AI": "6872145"
    },
    {
      "G": "5TH DIVISION",
      "G1": "5891211",
      "DOOR": "1246",
      "AA": "68",
      "AI": "5100214"
    },
    {
      "G": "7TH DIVISION",
      "G1": "2031892",
      "DOOR": "8907",
      "AA": "81",
      "AI": "8745524"
    },
    {
      "G": "8TH DIVISION",
      "G1": "4526892",
      "DOOR": "8877",
      "AA": "85",
      "AI": "8759544"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I am using following code in completebuilding.php :

```
<?php

$user[] = json_decode(file_get_contents("completehouse.php"), true);
$user[] = json_decode(file_get_contents("completeflat.php"), true);
$json_merge = json_encode($user);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_merge;
?>
```

But not getting desired output instead I getting different. Help me to save my time from manual merge.

Comment: you can use aray_merge https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: `$completeFlat['Value'] = array_merge($completeFlat['Value'], $completeHouse);`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus can you please write the full code of completebuilding.php to get desired output in json format

Comment: I just answered this very question less than a week ago.

Comment: @AlexBarker I am not getting exact output as above. Can you please give the correct code. See the code I have used.

Comment: Looks like the most recent one was deleted or something, here is another one that is basically the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083342/transform-array-structure-in-php/58084174#58084174